# .Net connectivty

Tags: c#, oracle10g, connection-string

I have Oracle 10g installed on one computer and I have Visual Studio 2008 on other. I have both the systems on LAN. I am trying to connect to Oracle database from the second computer in Server Explorer. I am getting the following message

System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

Also is the server name same as my second computer name

I am not really big on Oracle. Can somebody please tell me how to configure usernames and passwords with enough privelages to do administrative tasks

Lastly how would I achieve the same using connection string for creating OracleConnection assuming my database name is orcl, ip address is 192.168.0.5, server name is XYZ

Answer (score 0):

> System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

That error message is telling you that you need to install the Oracle client on your client machine, i.e. the one with Visual Studio on it. See the documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10131_02/install.htm).

There's a wealth of documentation out there describing how to configure and connect to Oracle databases. Here's Oracle's own [Client Post-Installation steps](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10131_02/post_install.htm#CACJIACC), which include instructions on how to verify your installation.

> Also is the server name same as my second computer name

Yes, the "server name" will be the name or IP address of the machine that your Oracle database is running on.

> Lastly how would I achieve the same using connection string for creating OracleConnection assuming my database name is orcl, ip address is 192.168.0.5, server name is XYZ

[This section](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10131_02/post_install.htm#CHDGAFAG) of the documentation I've linked to above describes the different ways of connecting with a given set of credentials.